# Measurable Functions $g(x)=f(x^2)$

Tags: measure-theory

$f: {\mathbb R} \rightarrow{\mathbb R}$

If $g: {\mathbb R} \rightarrow{\mathbb R}$,  $g(x)=f(x^2)$ measurable, then $f$ is also measurable?

I try to use the definition to measurable functions with the inverse function of $g$, but it doesn't work so good for me..

Thank you for your help.

Comment: No. Think about an $f$ with very bad behaviour on $(-\infty, 0)$, and good behaviour on $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: @T.Bongers: I need to work on my typing speed :-). (Or maybe my thinking speed!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, let $f$ be a function that is not measurable, but is zero for $x \ge 0$. Then $g$ will be measurable because $g(x) = f(x^2) = 0$, but $f$ is not measurable.

Comment: I try to find example for such non-measurable function...
Can I say that such function exists because always exists non-measurable set?

Comment: Yes, but it is not trivial to see that such sets exist. (See http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Existence_of_Non-Measurable_Sets, for example). If $A$ is not measurable, then the function $1_A$ is not measurable (because $(1_A)^{-1} \{1\} = A$).

Comment: I saw this proof in Royden's book :)
so $f$ can be $1_A$ when $A$ is not measurable, and $A$ contains negative numbers? so $f(x^2)=0$ as requested.

Comment: Well, at least one of $A_+=A \cap [0,\infty) $ or $A_- = A \cap (-\infty,0]$ will be non-measurable (otherwise $A$ would be measurable.) If only $A_+$ is non measurable, then use $-A_+$.